# line-height: normal it doesn't work on mobile and I cut the text with custom font

Tags: html, css

I have a site with a custom font and from a pc with chrome and the rest of the browsers work but on mobile the text is cut to me.
i tried to remove the line-height: normal that i had set from destkop via css and i saw that i get the same result that i see on mobile,
I think line-height doesn't work for me on smartphone and I don't understand why.

html

```
<h3 class="text-title text-start">title</h3>
```

css

```
@font-face{font-family: lostFont; src: url(../font/XtreemFat_Demo.ttf);}
.text-title{font-family: lostFont; line-height: normal; display: block; vertical-align: middle;}
```

Comment: What happens when you use a numeric value for line-height?

Comment: how normal gets interpreted depends on the user agent so perhaps the phone browser doesn't do it large enough for that font - as CBroe says, I would try using a numeric value instead - desktop browsers usually interpret normal as 1.2